# Обновление до Xcode 7.2 / Provisioning profile + SSKeyChain и черный экран

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7

После обновления Xcode с 6 версии до 7.2, каждый раз стало появляться окно.
Причем появился баг - в месте кода, где используется keychain, при запуске приложения на устройстве почему-то теперь черный экран. До смены версии все было нормально. Связываю это с обновлением и глюком keychain ([вот инфа, где говорится что при смене профиля изменяется и связка ключей](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30472475/4579593))

При запуске же на эмуляторе - все так же в норме.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Симулятору не нужна привязка к аккаунту, по этому на нем все билдиться. Возможно для того что бы решить вашу проблему с начало необходимо прописать Bundle ID(Targets->General->Bundle Identifier), потом пофиксить code signing identity(Targets->Build Settings->code signing identity). Еще может быть ваш iДевайс(его UUID) просто не прописан в профиле разработчика.

Comment: Последний пункт точно есть, проверял. Два предыдущих на днях обязательно проверю. Спасибо.

Comment: Bundle ID проверил - такой же как и до обновления версии.
code signing identity - developer стоит.

Comment: Странно, дает выбрать имя профиля, а когда билдится на устройство - меняет на atuomatic. Сейчас вот надо заливать новую версию и большие сомнения чтоб не сбился профиль для приложения. Очень этого не хочется - потеряю все связки ключей на устройствах пользователей......

Comment: Создайте себе новые сертификаты, а старые удалите